# Check if a DataGridView/BindSource have changed data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a WinForms app with a datagridview and a bindingsource.  I want the user to confirm changes before I save them to the database.

I don't want to pop up the confirmation dialog unless I know the user has made changes.  So I need a way to check if changes have been made.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `BindingSource.ListChanged` to rig a crude test - set a flag when the event is fired (you'll probably have to clear the flag once binding has completed).

But what is the data? For example, LINQ-to-SQL and DataTable both offer ways of querying for changes... (`DataTable.GetChanges()` and `DataContext.GetChangeSet()`). Most DAL-based mechanisms will usually have a way to do this too.

Answer (score 1):

if you're (ultimately) binding to a datatable you can check the rowstate for Changed or Added